# Restrict access to certain endpoints of a service

Tags: web-services, devops, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, endpoint

I want to deploy a webservice with multiple endpoints. Some endpoints should be accessible with no authentication, and will be called in the client app (eg. `/public/a`). However, I, as the API developper, want to be able to trigger some functions securely through other endpoints (eg. `/private/b/`).

I can't manage to find what are the best practices to do so, and what level should this authentication take place.

I am planning to deploy the service on AWS ECS, and use AWS API Gateway.

In API gateway, I can't find a way to apply different authentications for different endpoints.